# lag/lead N time periods over a grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, lag, plm

I'm grouping some variables and lagging (4 time periods) but I get `NA` values. I've tried using `dplyr::lag` and `plm::lag`

```
test = structure(list(cnty90 = c(1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 
                                 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1015, 
                                 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 
                                 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 
                                 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1039, 1039), 
                      year = c(1868, 1872, 1876, 1880, 1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 1900,
                               1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924, 1928, 1868, 1872, 1876, 1880,
                               1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 1900, 1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924,
                               1928, 1868, 1872, 1876, 1880, 1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 1900, 1904,
                               1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924, 1928, 1868, 1872), 
                      numdailies = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                     0, 2,2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

**using dplyr**

```
test %>% 
    group_by(cnty90, year) %>% 
    mutate(numdailies_l1 = lag(numdailies, n = 1),
           changedailies_for=lead(numdailies, n=1))

# A tibble: 50 x 6
# Groups:   cnty90, year [50]
   cnty90  year numdailies numdailies_l1 changedailies changedailies_for
    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>
 1   1005  1868          0            NA            NA                NA
 2   1005  1872          0            NA            NA                NA
 3   1005  1876          0            NA            NA                NA
 4   1005  1880          0            NA            NA                NA
 5   1005  1884          2            NA            NA                NA
 6   1005  1888          2            NA            NA                NA
 7   1005  1892          2            NA            NA                NA
 8   1005  1896          1            NA            NA                NA
 9   1005  1900          1            NA            NA                NA
10   1005  1904          1            NA            NA                NA
11   1005  1908          1            NA            NA                NA
12   1005  1912          1            NA            NA                NA
13   1005  1916          1            NA            NA                NA
14   1005  1920          1            NA            NA                NA
15   1005  1924          1            NA            NA                NA
16   1005  1928          1            NA            NA                NA
17   1015  1868          0            NA            NA                NA
18   1015  1872          0            NA            NA                NA
19   1015  1876          0            NA            NA                NA
20   1015  1880          0            NA            NA                NA
```

---

**using data.table**

```
test = data.table::data.table(test)
test[, ":=" (numdailies_l1 = lag(numdailies, n = 1),
             changedailies=numdailies-numdailies_l1,
             changedailies_for=lead(numdailies, n=1)), by = .(cnty90, year)]
```

## What I need to get

```
# A tibble: 20 x 6
   cnty90  year numdailies numdailies_l1 changedailies changedailies_for
    <int> <int>      <int>         <int>         <int>             <int>
 1   1005  1868          0            NA            NA                 0
 2   1005  1872          0             0             0                 0
 3   1005  1876          0             0             0                 0
 4   1005  1880          0             0             0                 2
 5   1005  1884          2             0             2                 0
 6   1005  1888          2             2             0                 0
 7   1005  1892          2             2             0                -1
 8   1005  1896          1             2            -1                 0
 9   1005  1900          1             1             0                 0
10   1005  1904          1             1             0                 0
11   1005  1908          1             1             0                 0
12   1005  1912          1             1             0                 0
13   1005  1916          1             1             0                 0
14   1005  1920          1             1             0                 0
15   1005  1924          1             1             0                 0
16   1005  1928          1             1             0                NA
17   1015  1868          0            NA            NA                 0
18   1015  1872          0             0             0                 0
19   1015  1876          0             0             0                 0
20   1015  1880          0             0             0                 0
```

Comment: Try not to group by year.  `test %>%  group_by(cnty90) %>%...`

Comment: @Dave2e It works!! . Why?.  If I load a `data` from `data("Crime", package = "plm")` I can use `group_by(county, year)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to group by year.  `test %>%  group_by(cnty90) %>%...`

When you are grouping, you are actually splitting the original data frame into a series of smaller data frames, with each "new" piece holding the grouping variables equal.

In your provided sample:

```
  cnty90  year numdailies numdailies_l1 changedailies changedailies_for
    <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>
 1   1005  1868          0            NA            NA                NA
 2   1005  1872          0            NA            NA                NA
 3   1005  1876          0            NA            NA                NA
 4   1005  1880          0            NA            NA                NA
 5   1005  1884          2            NA            NA                NA
```

For every combination of "Cntry90" and "year" there is only 1 row each, thus there are no other rows to lag, thus creating the NA.

By only grouping by cnty90 variable, there are now 16 rows for cnty90 =1005 thus the ability to perform the lag function. The same will also apply when cnty90 =1015

Comment: So, Do always I need to check `duplicates` values to know if I have to put inside `group_by` the `year`?

Comment: It is not a question of duplicates, it is a question of what belongs in each group.   You should only group the relevant variables and no more.  In this case, are you comparing trends by "cnty and year" or just by "cnty"?  Either answer may be correct depending on the question you are trying to answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `plm`-based solution using the panel-aware data structure `pdata.frame` would be as follows.

It seems like you want to lag row-wise while `plm::lag` lags time-wise per default. As your data does not have observations for each year, you get all `NAs` when lagging by one year. Use argument `shift = "row"` to lag row-wise. Or use time-wise lagging but lag by 4 years (as all your observations are 4 years apart).

Using your sample data to illustrate the three approaches:

```
test <- structure(list(cnty90 = c(1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 
                           1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1005, 1015, 
                           1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 
                           1015, 1015, 1015, 1015, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 
                           1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1031, 1039, 1039), 
                year = c(1868, 1872, 1876, 1880, 1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 1900,
                         1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924, 1928, 1868, 1872, 1876, 1880,
                         1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 1900, 1904, 1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924,
                         1928, 1868, 1872, 1876, 1880, 1884, 1888, 1892, 1896, 1900, 1904,
                         1908, 1912, 1916, 1920, 1924, 1928, 1868, 1872), 
                numdailies = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 2,2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
library(plm)
ptest <- pdata.frame(test, index = c("cnty90", "year"))

# lag row-wise:
ptest$numdailies_lagr <- plm::lag(ptest$numdailies, shift = "row")

# compare to lag time-wise by 1 year
ptest$numdailies_lag <- plm::lag(ptest$numdailies)

# lag time-wise by 4 years
ptest$numdailies_lag4 <- plm::lag(ptest$numdailies, k = 4L, shift = "time")

print(ptest)
#>           cnty90 year numdailies numdailies_lagr numdailies_lag numdailies_lag4
#> 1005-1868   1005 1868          0              NA             NA              NA
#> 1005-1872   1005 1872          0               0             NA               0
#> 1005-1876   1005 1876          0               0             NA               0
#> 1005-1880   1005 1880          0               0             NA               0
#> 1005-1884   1005 1884          2               0             NA               0
#> 1005-1888   1005 1888          2               2             NA               2
#> 1005-1892   1005 1892          2               2             NA               2
#> 1005-1896   1005 1896          1               2             NA               2
#> 1005-1900   1005 1900          1               1             NA               1
#> 1005-1904   1005 1904          1               1             NA               1
#> 1005-1908   1005 1908          1               1             NA               1
#> 1005-1912   1005 1912          1               1             NA               1
#> 1005-1916   1005 1916          1               1             NA               1
#> 1005-1920   1005 1920          1               1             NA               1
#> 1005-1924   1005 1924          1               1             NA               1
#> 1005-1928   1005 1928          1               1             NA               1
#> 1015-1868   1015 1868          0              NA             NA              NA
#> 1015-1872   1015 1872          0               0             NA               0
#> 1015-1876   1015 1876          0               0             NA               0
#> 1015-1880   1015 1880          0               0             NA               0
#> 1015-1884   1015 1884          0               0             NA               0
#> 1015-1888   1015 1888          2               0             NA               0
#> 1015-1892   1015 1892          2               2             NA               2
#> 1015-1896   1015 1896          1               2             NA               2
#> 1015-1900   1015 1900          1               1             NA               1
#> 1015-1904   1015 1904          2               1             NA               1
#> 1015-1908   1015 1908          2               2             NA               2
#> 1015-1912   1015 1912          2               2             NA               2
#> 1015-1916   1015 1916          1               2             NA               2
#> 1015-1920   1015 1920          1               1             NA               1
#> 1015-1924   1015 1924          1               1             NA               1
#> 1015-1928   1015 1928          1               1             NA               1
#> 1031-1868   1031 1868          0              NA             NA              NA
#> 1031-1872   1031 1872          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1876   1031 1876          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1880   1031 1880          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1884   1031 1884          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1888   1031 1888          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1892   1031 1892          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1896   1031 1896          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1900   1031 1900          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1904   1031 1904          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1908   1031 1908          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1912   1031 1912          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1916   1031 1916          1               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1920   1031 1920          0               1             NA               1
#> 1031-1924   1031 1924          0               0             NA               0
#> 1031-1928   1031 1928          0               0             NA               0
#> 1039-1868   1039 1868          0              NA             NA              NA
#> 1039-1872   1039 1872          0               0             NA               0
```